# Do 'gaunt' and 'gauntlet' have something in common?

Tags: etymology, roots

This two words *'gaunt'* and *'gauntlet'* sound similar and have a common root. But their meanings are unrelated. Can it be that *gauntlet* is somehow derived from *gaunt*? If yes, then I want to know etymology.

Comment: You can always use http://etymonline.com as a start.

Comment: Can you clarify which "gauntlet" you're talking about? There are two, with different etymologies: the glove one and the one in "run the gauntlet"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Gauntlet](https://www.etymonline.com/word/gauntlet): protective gloves used as a form of armour: late Middle English: from Old French gantelet, diminutive of gant ‘glove’, of Germanic origin.

[Gaunt](https://www.etymonline.com/word/gaunt): bony and emaciated in appearance: 15th Century: perhaps of Scandinavian origin; compare Norwegian dialect gand tall lean person.

I don't think they share a common root.